# possible to HTTP GET without query string being shown in url browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this url

`window.location.href = '/Cart/?id=22';`

browser url will show `localhost:12345/Cart/?id=22`, is it possible to hide the `/?id=22` from the url?

Comment: Yes you can use HTTP POST

Comment: @joyBlanks: You cannot use post with that link.

Comment: If you want that to happen, please see this: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: url rewrithing.......!